# OpenCart - Create unique product option from within product edit page

Tags: opencart

Would it be possible (with some modification or maybe an existing plugin) to create unique product options from within the product edit page? Those options then only assigned to that product?

In total across all my products, I'll have around 500 'options'. Each product of mine has about 5 options, rather than having to go to the OPTIONS section which will then list all 500, I'd rather input them directly from within the product edit page.

As it stands I cannot, I have to create the 'option value' elsewhere, then go back in to the product edit page area and then assign the option.

As you'll see in my attachment, you can only select already created product 'options value' from the product edit page, not create them here.

[image]